# ¿Cómo evitar autocompletado de usuario y contraseña en formulario de registro de usuarios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un formulario en el cual registro usuarios nuevos para una aplicación web.

El problema está en que los campos de usuario y contraseña los rellena con el usuario y contraseña que tengo guardados para iniciar sesión. Ya intenté con el autocomplete="off" para el formulario y aunque si funciona y no muestra ninguna sugerencia para los demás campos, para los mencionados anteriormente sigue mostrando lo mismo.

[image: El formulario mencionado]

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Edito: Aquí el código

```
<form class="needs-validation" id="formulario" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="Name">Nombre Completo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Campo Requerido.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="Usuario">Nombre Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Usuario" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Campo Requerido
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <?php $result = sqlsrv_query($conn_sis,"SELECT T0.Codigo, T0.Nombre, T0.Active FROM OSSS T0");?> 
            <label for="SAPnumber">Numero Empleado SAP</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="SAPnumber" required>
                   <?php while ($obj=sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {

                    if($obj->Codigo==-1){
                      ?>
                    <option value="-1">- Seleccione una opción -</option>
                  
                    <?php                      
                    }else{
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $obj->Codigo ?>"><?php echo $obj->Codigo." ".$obj->Nombre ?></option>
                
                <?php }}?>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Selecciona un mes.
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Agregue la fecha en que se solicita.
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="correo">Correo</label>
            <input type="mail" class="form-control" id="correo" placeholder="">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Agregue la fecha en que se solicita.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="correo">Puesto</label>
              <input type="puesto" class="form-control" id="puesto" placeholder="">
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Agregue la fecha en que se solicita.
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                <label for="day">Dia de Nacimiento</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="day" required>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Selecciona un día.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="mes">Mes</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="mes" required>
                  <option value="1">Enero</option>
                  <option value="2">Febrero</option>
                  <option value="3">Marzo</option>
                  <option value="4">Abril</option>
                  <option value="5">Mayo</option>
                  <option value="6">Junio</option>
                  <option value="7">Julio</option>
                  <option value="8">Agosto</option>
                  <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
                  <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                  <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                  <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Selecciona un mes.
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="year">Año</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="year" placeholder="" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Escribe el año de nacimiento.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <label for="testigo">Foto para Perfil</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">FOTO</span>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="filephoto" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="filephoto">Elegir archivo ( JPG / GIF / PNG )</label>
            </div>
            </div>



            
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Agregar Usuario</button>
</form>
```

Como se puede ver, el autocomplete está puesto en el form y aún así se siguen mostrando el usuario y la contraseña en el formulario de registro.

Comment: Hace falta el código del formulario para ver que sucede, autocomplete=off deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Si `autocomplete="off"` está en `<form action="#"></form>`, está bien. Al insertar **autocomplete="off"** en la etiqueta **form**, desabilita en todos los inputs del formulario.

```
<form action="#" autocomplete="off">

  <input type="text" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al final, la manera de resolverlo fue agregar autocomplete="new-password" al input de contraseña. Eso evita que se siga autocompletando.